# How can I achieve this: Table with 2 cells, Links in first cell change the text displayed in second cell. All on same page

Tags: html, html-table

How can I have a table with 1 row and 2 cells, and have 'links' in the first cell which can be clicked to display different information (text or links) in the second cell.

```
    <!doctype html>
 <head>
    <title>
        Our first document: Hello World!
    </title>

    <h1>
        About Myself
    </h1>
    <p align = "left">
      blah blah blah
    </p>
</head>

<body>
   <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 100%; width: 50%">
            <h1>
              <a href = "http://webprojects.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/ag316/my_homepage.html">
                About myself 
              </a> &nbsp;
              <br>
              <a href = "http://webprojects.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/ag316/my_CV.html">
                My CV
              </a> &nbsp;
              <br>
              <a href = "">
                My Hobby
              </a> &nbsp;
              <br>
              <a href = "">
                Links
              </a> &nbsp;
            </h1>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 100%; width: 20%">
            //code
        </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
    <h1>
    My Hobby
    </h1>
    <p align = "left">
      blah blah blah
    </p>
    <h1>
        My CV
    </h1>
    <p align = "left">
      You can download my CV   
      <a href = "http://webprojects.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/ag316/my_CV.html">
        here 
      </a>
    </p>
    <h1>
        Links
    </h1>
    <p align = "left">
        I like to visit the following websites :
        <br>
        <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/">YouTube </a>
        <br>
        <a href = "https://www.google.co.uk/">Google </a>
        <br>
        <a href = "https://inbox.google.com/u/0/">Inbox </a>
        <br>
    </p>
</body>
```

Here's what I have, its just empty code taking place of actual useful information. So when I click the 'links' link the in the left cell I want to see the links paragraph in the right. So far the links paragraph is below the table as I don't know how to use the same table cell for displaying different paragraphs of text depending on which link is pressed.

Comment: Are you going to use tables for page layout? Tables are for displaying data not to dispose data on page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i truly understand you, you need an `iframe` in cell 2 and change its src with click on links:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('td a').click(function() {
       $('#frame1').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
       return false; 
    });
});
```

I assume that your `iframe` has `id="frame1"`.